Is there a simple conceptual proof of Poisson summation formula analogous to the inavariance of trace under basis change?
Compared to Plancherel's formula, which simply says the Fourier transform is an isometry on the space of $L^2$ functions, Poisson summation formula is always mysterious. There are several posts that highlight its relation with better known phenomenon such as the connection with Selberg Trace formula, or by looking at the trace of a special kernel function $K(x, y) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x - y + z)$ computed in 2 different ways. But the former seems to be a generalization of Poisson summation itself, whereas the latter feels contrived with the special kernel $K$.
I am looking for a motivating pseudo-proof along the line of the invariance of the trace of an operator with respect to change of basis, $\rm{Tr} X = \rm{Tr} U X U^{-1}$. So maybe the Fourier transform can be viewed as a conjugation operator, and the space of $L^2$ functions can be viewed as a space of operators? This is purely speculative, but to be honestly that's what I thought was going on when I first saw the connection with Selberg Trace formula.

I have also wondered this!
